# Need to display alternative text when query results return no match

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

My script cycles through multiple environments and if a user is found, it prints out their ID. The desired output is as follows:

```
environment1
<user_id>
```

However, my script is currently working to print out every environment even if there isn't a user id, like follows:

```
environment1
<user_id>
environment2
environment3
environment4
<user_id>
```

I would like the code to print out "NO USER FOUND" if the user_id does not exist, rather than excluding the environment altogether.

The code below is what is being utilized:

```
#log it all
{

  echo "environment"
  sshpass -p $ldappw ssh $ldapuser@12.345.67.89 'mysql --skip-column-names -hhost -u user -ppassword database -e \
"select user_id from users where first like '"'%${first_name}%' and last like '%${last_name}%';"'"' 


} > $log
```

Any help would be much appreciated for this issue. Unfortunately I'm just beginning to learn more advanced MySQL and Linux command line tools and am not quite proficient enough to know how to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
select ifnull(user_id,'NO USER FOUND') from users where first like '"'%${first_name}%' and last like '%${last_name}%';
```